# Constraint logic programming in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, constraint-programming

Is it possible to do [constraint logic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLP(R)) in Racket? For example, can these problems be solved in Racket: http://people.sju.edu/~jhodgson/clp/howto_clpr.html or the SENDMORE problem on this page: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Constraint_Logic_Programming . I also could not find Racket and Scheme on these pages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_logic_programming and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming

I see minikanren: http://io.livecode.ch/learn/webyrd/webmk  and  http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/dfriedman/miniKanren.plt/1/1/doc.txt and https://github.com/miniKanren/Racket-miniKanren  but cannot find real examples.

Comment: There are examples of constraint programming in *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* using Scheme. So it can be done in Racket. See https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node65.html and following digital circuit simulator.

Comment: Kanren is "relational programming". Search on Youtube. There are many talks illustrating how to use Kanren in Scheme or Closure.

Comment: Note that Racket comes with [MiniKanren](https://docs.racket-lang.org/minikanren/index.html) and [Racklog](https://docs.racket-lang.org/racklog/index.html) for logic programming.

Comment: Rosette supports several SMT solvers as well as the CPLEX mixed-integer programming solver. The Racket code is at https://github.com/emina/rosette/tree/master/rosette/solver